# Send email for approval/rejection

Tags: workflow, content-approval

We have enabled approval on a document library in SharePoint 2010 and would like the system to send an email to someone who can approve/reject when the user publishes a major version. A few questions:

- How do you set up SharePoint to automatically email members of a site's Approver's group when a document is published?
- Can SharePoint automatically email the document editor when the document is approved/rejected?
- Can this same process be set up for the items in a publishing Pages library?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of these can be achieved. If you have SharePoint designer, you can enter the lists through that and attach workflows on Item Adding, Item Added, Item Updating, Item Updated etc.

Through the SPD UI you can easily setup flows to send out emails to specific users and/or groups on above mentioned phases of the items process. This can also be done on the publishing Page libary.

Comment: Thanks, Ziga. The first video there talked about starting workflow manually. Can it be fired off automatically when an item in a list is edited? Also, can we get the current user's Active Directory login ID to use for sending emails?

Comment: Usually the workflow triggers automatic when it's attached to an item process. Regarding getting user information, that too is possible. When you add the email action in your workflow you'll be having the option to make a "template" to be used, in this "template" you'll be able to insert whatever user info available through the UI